# How to add as exposed filter a product attribute in Commerce's orders view?

Tags: commerce

I have a drupal 8 commerce website.
The Orders page is a view that comes with commerce where all the orders are listed.
Is it possible to add/create ( on the website or programatically ) an exposed filter based on a PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE to show all the orders containing a value of that product attribute?

For example: for a product attribute called ORIGIN, I would like an exposed filter in the orders view that would allow me to choose between 2 values: Los Angeles or San Francisco.

Some orders will show up in both because they will have different products with different ORIGIN value product attributes.

I tried to modify the orders view but I couldnt find any product attributes nor a relationship to products. I tried to add a relationship to order item but that didn't help expose any of the product attribute fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product's attributes are set through the product variation. You need to add the Variations through a relationship and you will have attributes available there.

[image: Products Variation form]

After that your attributes can be added as exposed filters.

[image: A view]

Sorry I don´t have any English sites available but pay close attention to captures.

Comment: thanks man... for some reason the product variation did not show up in the relationship unless i added order_item first... thanks, you're the man

Comment: Thats correct since orders are composed by order items and order items are linked to products variations no the product itself, I forgot to clarify that in my answer